# How to overwrite list attachment in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

i am trying to attach a document in list with the same name as previous document. in list, we don't have "Overwrite existing files" option. That s why i am getting error. Kindly tell me how can i overwrite previous document.

Error Description below.

**The specified name is already in use.
The document or folder name was not changed.  To change the name to a different value, close this dialog and edit the properties of the document or folder.0x81020067**

i am unable to post a clear screen shot because i have 8 reputation only.

i am attaching in same list item only.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box attaching files with same name is not supported.
It is important that you deleted the file attached earlier since you want to attach the file with same name.

Otherwise you need to have custom solution to overwrite the file.